# Create a link from text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code

```
<div class="row1">
<em>My text</em>
</div>
```

How can I make a link like:

```
<div class="row1">
<em><a href="/mylink">My text</a></em>
</div>
```

I understand that the issue is a primitive but can not find the same simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.row1 em').html(function(i, contents) {
    return '<a href="/mylink">' + contents + '</a>';
});
```

or

```
 $('.row1 em').contents().wrapAll('<a href="/mylink" />');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) with [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$(".row1 em").contents().wrapAll("<a href='/mylink'></a>");
```

Comment: [That's what I said!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897680/create-a-link-from-text/6897723#6897723)

Comment: @Eric, sorry, I did not see your answer when I posted mine :)

Comment: It's ok. You remembered to post the docs links, which in many ways is better.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
$(".row1 em").contents().wrapAll("<a href='/mylink'></a>")
```

Comment: Duplicate of mine and [@Frédéric Hamidi's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897680/create-a-link-from-text/6897749#6897749) answer

Comment: then what...every one here is having right to write there suggestion if matches with other answer's what's problem in that...

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
$('.row1 em').wrap('<a href="/mylink" />');
```

Update: Since this will wrap the `<a>` tags around `<em>` instead its contents, the correct way is to use `$('.row1 em').contents().wrap('<a href="/mylink" />');` as Frederic stated

Comment: Wrong! That'll put the `<a>` around the `<em>`.

Comment: I don't see how changing the order in which those tags appear justifies a downvote. em inside a is perfectly valid

Comment: Possibly because that's _not what the question asked for_?

Comment: Yes, it's not quite as I described in the job, but none the less. this solution works and I am quite fit. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.row1 em').html().wrap('<a href="/mylink">');
```

Comment: Wrong! `.html()` returns a string!

Comment: Yep - you're right this answer is totally wrong. I'm not going to edit it

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is to hyperlink the text, and you can afford alternate solutions, following achieves the same:

HTML:

```
<div class="row1">
    <em>My text</em>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row1 {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.em').click(function() {
    location.href = '/mylink';
});
```

Comment: No! Do not create links in JavaScript, they are horrible on usability. What if I don't have JS enabled? What if I want to open the link into another tab? What if I want to see where the link leads before clicking?

Comment: Agreed on other counts, but not on JS being disabled, since the question itself is tagged with javascript/jquery, and various other solutions too use jquery.